# Intuitive explanation of the fact that the Calculus of Constructions is not conservative over Higher-Order Logic

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, proof-assistants, calculus-of-constructions

Reading Barendregt's chapter “Lambda Calculi with Types” in the *Handbook of Logic in Computer Science (vol. 2: Computational Structures)* (Abramsky, Gabbay & Maibaum eds., 1992) I learned (*op. cit.* theorem 5.4.21) that Berardi and Geuvers proved in 1989 that the Calculus of Constructions is not conservative over Higher-Order Predicate Logic, i.e., there is a sentence which is not provable in the latter but is (under the propositions-as-types interpretation) the type of a term of the former.

Barendregt gives an account of both proofs by Berardi and Geuvers (I was unable to get my hands on the original works; in fact, Berardi's is cited as “personal communication” by Barendregt): this account isn't too hard too follow, but I feel like I'm kind of missing the whole point, because I don't “see” where the typing rules of the CoC differ from the derivation rules of HOL in a way that makes the constructed term invalid as a proof.

So, **questions**:

- Can someone give an informal/intuitive explanation of *what is going on* here?  As in: what went wrong?  At what point exactly did the typing system and the logical system diverge?
- Specifically, if we try to interpret the term constructed by Berardi or by Geuvers as a proof, *where exactly does it go wrong?*  I'd like to put my finger on the exact logical rule which isn't allowed in Higher-Order Predicate Logic but which is permitted as a typing rule in the Calculus of Construction (and trying to extract this from Barendregt's account leaves me lost in a maze of twisty little notations all alike).
- In practice, what does this mean for a proof assistant like Coq which is based on the Calculus of Constructions?  Will Coq accept the term in question as a valid proof?

---

**Edit** (2023-12-18): For completeness of CSTheorySE, here is a paraphrase of the account Barendregt gives of Geuvers's proof:

Consider the context $\Gamma$ and type $B$ defined by:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Gamma &:= A:*^s,\;c:A \\
B &:= \Pi Q:(*^p\to *^p).\, \Pi q:*^p.\,
(Q(\Pi x:A.q) \to \exists q':*^p. Q(q'\to q))
\end{aligned}
$$
This is in the [pure type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_type_system) which Barendregt calls “$\lambda\mathrm{PRED}\omega$”, defined by:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\textrm{sorts}&*^p,*^s,*^f,\square^p,\square^s\\
\textrm{axioms}&*^p:\square^p,\,*^s:\square^s\\
\textrm{rules}&(*^p,*^p),\,(*^s,*^p),\,(\square^p,*^p),\\
&(*^s,*^s,*^f),\,(*^s,*^f,*^f),\,(*^s,\square^p),\,(\square^p,\square^p)
\end{array}
$$
(Barendregt comments that $*^s$ is the sort of “sets”, $*^p$ is the sort of “propositions” and $*^f$ is the sort of first-order functions between sets),
and we define “$\exists x:S.A$” for $A:*^p$ and $S:*^s$ by
$$
\exists x:S.A \;:=\; \Pi\gamma:*^p.\,(\Pi x:S.(A\to\gamma))\to\gamma
$$

Then **(1)** the translation $|B|$ of $B$ into $\lambda C$, obtained by removing all superscripts on $*$ and $\square$, is inhabited, but **(2)** $B$ considered as a formula is not derivable in $\lambda\mathrm{PRED}\omega$.

To justify **(1)**, it is enough to construct $C_0$ of type $(Q(\Pi x:A.q) \to \exists q':*. Q(q'\to q))$ in context $A:*,\;c:A,\;Q:(*\to *),\;q:*$.  Now note that $Q(\Pi x:A.q) = Q(A\to q)$ and the type
$$
\begin{aligned}
& Q(\Pi x:A.q) \to \exists q':*. Q(q'\to q)\\
=\;& Q(A\to q) \to (\Pi \alpha:*. (\Pi q':*. (Q(q'\to q)\to\alpha))\to\alpha)
\end{aligned}
$$
is inhabited by
$$
\lambda y:Q(A\to q).\,
\lambda \alpha:*.\,
\lambda f:(\Pi q':*. (Q(q'\to q)\to\alpha)).\,
f A y
$$

As for **(2)**, Barendregt doesn't say much: if $C$ has type $B$ in $\lambda\mathrm{PRED}\omega$ then $CQqr\alpha t$ has type $\alpha$ in context
$$
\begin{array}{c}
A:*^s,\;c:A,\;Q:(*^p\to *^p),\;q:*^p,\\
r:(Q(\Pi x:A.q)),\;\alpha:\alpha^p,\\
t:(\Pi q':*^p. (Q(q'\to q)\to\alpha))
\end{array}
$$
and Barendregt just writes “by considering the possible normal forms of $CQqr\alpha t$ it can be shown that this is impossible”.

Comment: To clarify, when you say propositions-as-types, do you intend to interpret $\exists$ as $\Sigma$?

Comment: It seems difficult to access the literature you cite on-line. Would you be so kind as to quickly outline the arguments you're talking about?

Comment: https://x.com/gro_tsen/status/1736401134598660096?s=20

Comment: @AndrejBauer [Here is a scan](http://www.madore.org/~david/.misc/barendregt1992.pdf) of Barendregt's paper. Relevant section is the pages numbered 264–265, which are 148–149 in this PDF. \[This comment will self-desctruct in a few days.\]

Comment: @AndrejBauer I could cop out by saying that “propositions-as-types” is something Barendregt writes, not I. But since neither the Calculus of Construction nor the logical systems he compares it with have $\Sigma$ or $\exists$ in his paper (the systems are impredicative so he defines them $\Sigma$ or $\exists$ impredicatively), the question of how to interpret them doesn't arise. ❧ I'll edit the question soon to include Geuvers's term, but I can't really summarize the argument since its essence escapes me.

Answer (score 10):

I do not know if this answers your question, but in [Propositions as [Types]](https://doi.org/10.1093/logcom/14.4.447) we communicate in Remark 6.6 an observation by Thierry Coquand, namely that the statement
$$
(\forall x .\, \exists y .\, R(x,y))
\Rightarrow
\forall x, x' .\, \exists y, y' .\, R(x,y) \land R(x',y') \land (x = x' \Rightarrow y = y'))
$$
is not provable in intuitionistic first-order logic, but is inhabited under propositions-as-types. Apparently this goes back to an unpublished note by Mints.

Comment: Thanks for the example, here is the proof in Coq: 
```Lemma foo: forall (A B: Type) (R:A->B->Prop) (H:forall x, {y | R x y}),
forall x x', exists y y', (R x y /\ R x' y' /\ (x=x' -> y=y')).
Proof.
intros.
exists (proj1_sig (H x)).
exists (proj1_sig (H x')).
repeat split.
apply (proj2_sig (H x)).
apply (proj2_sig (H x')).
intro;subst; auto.
Qed.```

Comment: Thanks. Minor quibble: you're mixing `{... | ...}` and `exists`, the Curry-Howard version should use `{... | ...}` everywhere. And the "real" Curry-Howard would use `Type` instead of `Prop`. (Your proof woudl still work, of course.)

Comment: But it can be proved with ```exists``` in the hypothesis, right ?

Comment: No, that's the whole point of the example.

Comment: Is this related to the axiom of choice in some way? Is it correct to say that in first-order intuitionistic logic we can't extract a choice function from `forall a, exists b, ...` but we can do so (in `Type`) in proposition-as-types?

Comment: @chi: That indeed explains why we can inhabit the type-theoretic version, although it says little about why th logical version is not provable (perhaps there is a proof that avoids choice).

Comment: Does this statement have a particular name in the literature?

Comment: I'll ask Thierry Coquand tomorrow, as I happen to be in the same city as he is.

Comment: @AndrejBauer sorry I meant "can't be proved", of course